# attempting to connect to R from C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to connect to R using C#. I installed R.Net and referenced it my project. This is my first attempt at C#. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

This is the sample C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using RDotNet;

namespace RNet_Calculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        // set up basics and create RDotNet instance 
        // if anticipated install of R is not found, ask the user to find it. 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string dlldir = @"C:\Users\R\R-2.15.2\bin\x64";
            bool r_located = false;

            while (r_located == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    REngine.SetDllDirectory(dlldir);
                    REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet");
                    r_located = true;
                }

                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(@"Unable to find R installation's \bin\i386 folder. 
                    Press OK to attempt to locate it.");


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

this is the Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Form1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the image is hardly legible.

Comment: I don't think there is problem with R.NET...

Comment: What does your `Program` class look like? Is it placed in the `RNet_Calculator` namespace?

Comment: Looks like your problem is with the designer generated part of the form code. Note it's complaining that there is no method `calc_Load`. Somewhere you probably have an event tied to a non-existent handler.

Comment: It looks like it's a problem with your program's references, namespace or configuration rather than a problem with R. You might want to post the code for program.cs, and remove the "R" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually nothing to do with R.  You have probably overwritten the namespace in one place and not in another.  You have the code

```
namespace RNet_Calculator
```

in your form code.  If you open `Form1.designer.cs` you will probably see

```
namespace Form1
```

Just change the namespace from `Form1` to `RNet_Calculator` and your errors should disappear.

**EDIT**

In response to your edit, you should either change the single `RNET_Calculator` namespace back to `Form1` or you should (but don't have to) change the `Form1` namespace in your Program.cs file (and any other files in your project) as well.  Doing this means you also should change the namespace in your project properties.  Right-click your project, select Properties, and in the Application tab (should be the first one to open), change the "Default namespace" textbox to `RNET_Calculator`.